# Create function to remove duplicates from Haskell list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to build a function that takes the first element of a string, and removes all other elements equal to it from the string. Then does the same for the second character.

Ie - "Heello" would become "Helo" and "Chocolate" "Chlate"

My original attempt

```
removeSuccessor :: String -> String
removeSuccessor x = [c | c <- x, x ! `elem` c]
```

But that doesn't seem to work.. suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at `Data.List.nub`?

Comment: By `x ! \`elem\` c`, I think you probably mean `not (elem c x)`. Haskell doesn't use `!` for logical negation, and `elem` takes its arguments in the other order (its type is `a -> [a] -> Bool`, not `[a] -> a -> Bool`.

Comment: `not (elem c x)` is the same thing as `c \`notElem\` x`

Comment: Rewrote the function as:

removeDifferent :: String -> String
removeDifferent x = [c | c <- x, not (`elem` c x)]

Still not working :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could keep a set of all elements seen and only keep the current one if it hasn't been seen yet:

```
import Data.Set
removeDups :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a -> [a]
removeDups [] sofar = []
removeDups (x:rest) sofar
     | member x sofar = (removeDups rest sofar)
     | otherwise      = x:(removeDups rest (insert x sofar))
```

Usage:

```
removeDups "Heello" empty    -- "Helo"
removeDups "Chocolate" empty -- "Choclate"
```

Run time is `O(n log n)`, I think.

Or you can use [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html) from `Data.List`:

```
Prelude Data.List> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> nub "Heello"
"Helo"
Prelude Data.List> nub "Chocolate"
"Choclate"
```

Run-time is `O(n^2)`.